How to mock #Preview with a view expecting an Error as parameter?
I have a view showing error information which is working fine. The information is wrapped inside a struct. But I couldn’t figure out how to mock the expected data to show the view in preview canvas.
Struct to store the error information.
struct ErrorWrapper: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let error: Error
    let guidance: String
    let errorStyle: ErrorStyle
}

Preview with the missing part for the Error.
#Preview {
    //how to instanciate an error?
    static var errorWrapper = ErrorWrapper(error, "guidance", ErrorStyle.ok)
    ErrorViewOk(errorWrapper: errorWrapper)
}


Error is a protocol so you can create a mock concrete type for it, something like:
enum MockError: Error {
    case invalidData
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(error: ErrorWrapper(MockError.invalidData,
                                    "Halo",
                                    ErrorStyle.ok))
}


Thanks for getting back. Using the #Preview leads to an ‘Ambiguous use of init(_:traits:body:)’ error message in the preview macro.

You can define variables in the Preview body as long as you explicitly «return» the View .

Sorry I didn't execute the code, simply remove the static var or add return ErrorViewOk + remove static as @ptit mentioned

Thanks. Yes that will solve the problem.

Alternatively I was able to solve the problem not using the #Preview macro.
struct ErrorViewOk_Preview: PreviewProvider {
enum MockError: Error {
    case invalidData
}
static var errorWrapper = ErrorWrapper(error: MockError.invalidData, guidance: "guidance", errorStyle: ErrorStyle.ok)

static var previews: some View {
    ErrorViewOk(errorWrapper: errorWrapper)
}

}
